# What's the proper way to write this short hand conditional ternary operator to compare two variables?

Tags: javascript, operators, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a shorthand conditional statement. Here's an example of the code:

```
const siteIdentifier = "bar";
const refOne = "foo";
const refTwo = "bar";

(siteIdentifier == refOne || refTwo) ? "primary" : "secondary";
```

I've also tried using `.match` and other variations but was unsuccessful with that as well.

I'm looking to compare the `siteIdentifier` string to two possible strings. If the strings match, we're returning `"primary"`. If it doesn't match one of the two, it returns `"secondary"`.

Comment: one way would be `(siteIdentifier == refOne || siteIdentifier ==  refTwo)` ... another one could be `~[refOne, refTwo].indexOf(siteIdentifier) ? "primary" : "secondary";`

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. If you want to throw that answer up I can mark it complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way would be

```
(siteIdentifier == refOne || siteIdentifier == refTwo) ? "primary" : "secondary";
```

... another one could be (more useful when you have many strings to match to)

```
~[refOne, refTwo].indexOf(siteIdentifier) ? "primary" : "secondary";
```

which is the same as

```
[refOne, refTwo].indexOf(siteIdentifier) >= 0 ? "primary" : "secondary";
```

Comment: I liked the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(siteIdentifier == refOne) ? "primary" : (siteIdentifier == refTwo ? "primary" : "secondary");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the completeness, an object with all possibillities together.

```
const obj = { foo: 'primary', bar: 'primary', default: 'secondary'};
x = obj[siteIdentifier] || obj.default;
```